# WCF serialization issue when moving existing class properties to newly created base class

Tags: wcf, soap

I'm seeing the serialization issue at the client side for the following scenario.

Let's say we have the following class and method in our service code

```
[DataContract]
public class Derived
{
    [DataMember]
    public string A { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string B { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string C { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

and the service interface has the method

```
    [OperationContract]
    Derived GetDerived();
```

Implementation of the method -

```
public Derived GetDerived()
{
    var d = new Derived() {A = "A", B = "B", C = "C", D = "D"};
    return d;
}
```

For this WCF service if I create the client proxy (by adding service reference) and do the GetDerived() call, everything works fine.

Let's change the entity in service code little bit

```
[DataContract]
public class Base
{
    [DataMember]
    public string B { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Derived : Base
{
    [DataMember]
    public string A { get; set; }        

    [DataMember]
    public string C { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string D { get; set; }
}
```

So in this case I created a new Base class and moved property 'B' to the Base class. With the same old proxy at the client side, if I do GetDerived call, I do not see the value of A properly serialized at the client side. However, the SOAP message for previous version and the current version is the same (only order changed). I came across this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813.aspx article explaining the ordering. Since I moved 'B' to base class, I don't see anyway to control it's order in derived class.

Is there any workaround to this problem? This breaks the backward compatibility to the client.

On the other hand, If I add the new property, let's say C1 to Derived class (or any existing class), it changes the order as well. How come this doesn't break the client? vs. the scenario that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Were you able to get a solution to this problem? If so, could you post it?

Comment: You can implement surrogates as explained here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/09/14/wcf-extensibility-serialization-surrogates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using the example above, I overloaded the property "B" in the derived class and had it refer to the Base class (I'm working in VB, sorry):

```
#region "This shenanigans prevents breaking the contract when moving some properties to the base class.
    <DataMember()> Public Overloads Property B() As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.B
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.B = value
        End Set
    End Property
#End Region
```

This way my base class methods can still operate on B.  If we ever get around to implementing wcf versioning, or have some other need to change the contract, I can strip out that overload in the derived class and everything should still just work.

-JG